# How to style sets of labels and fields in a form with pure CSS and get proper alignment?

Tags: css, forms, tablelayout

I'm asking as a last-ditch effort to comply with my conscience and do this with CSS. I want to layout this simple form using CSS, but I've spent two hours trying to get it and always end up with alignment issues. I did it in ten minutes using tables.

I need labels right-justified, the name row split in two, the labels properly vertically aligned with the input text, and all the right edges of the inputs to line up. What does it take to do this in CSS?

[image]

**EDIT:** Adding my CSS to see where I'm going wrong.

Here's as far as I got with the CSS:

```
.form_row {
    width: 500px;
}
.form_row label {
    text-align: right;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
#id_first_name, #id_last_name {
    width: 130px;
}
#id_email, #id_password {
    width: 300px;
}
```

The Markup:

```
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="id_first_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="id_first_name" type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input id="id_first_name" type="text" name="last_name" />
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email"/>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
    <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    <input id="id_password" type="password" name="password" />
</div>
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Best show your existing CSS approach so people can correct it.

Comment: could you use div with float:left?

Comment: Added the CSS. Yes, floating can be used to achieve the placement and ordering, but I can never get the right edges of line one to line up.

Comment: uuhh, why did Peter feel it necessary to edit my post to capitalize all of my 'css' references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tempted me into taking up the challenge :) I just about did it in 10 minutes using CSS.

As long as you're ok with tweaking `line-height`'s and settings dimensions in px for some elements I think its achievable.

Other things to note are how `font-size`, `padding` and `line-height`'s affect textboxes and their dimensions.

Have a look at this: http://jsbin.com/osibu3/4

Tested in IE6+, FF3.6+, Chrome, Safari

Pasting for reference as well:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,ul,li,form,button,fieldset { margin:0; padding:0 }
    body { font:normal 62.5% lucida grande, lucida sans unicode }
    #my-form { font-size:1.1em; width:500px; padding:20px; background:#E9E9E9;}
    #my-form fieldset { border:0; margin-bottom:2px; height:20px; line-height:18px; }
    #my-form fieldset label { width:70px; display:block; float:left; text-align:right; padding-right:5px; color:#61515C; }
    input.text { border:1px solid #ddd; font:inherit; font-size:11px; line-height:14px; height:14px; padding:2px;
      border-radius:2px; -moz-border-radius:2px; -webkit-border-radius:2px;}
    .text.long { width:395px }
    .text.short { width:193px }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" id="my-form">
    <fieldset class="name">
      <label for="first"><strong>Name:</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="first" value="first" class="text short"/>
      <input type="text"  name="last" value="last" class="text short"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="email"><strong>Email:</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="text long"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="password"><strong>Password:</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="password" class="text long"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sweet jesus, that was fast. This is exactly what I was looking for, I'm gonna study this for a bit. Thank you so much, Moin!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

The blueprint css framework can help you with tabular layout with divs.  It has simple usage and good documentation.

It's hard to give another answer with such little information in your question.